# search and replace using regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, stl, boost-xpressive

I have a string to be searched

```
QString sObjectName = "looolok"
```

The regex_search for ".?o" results in 3 matched texts which I push to a vector matchedText

```
"lo" "oo" "lo"
```

Now I my replace text is "o"
So I would expect the str to be changed to

```
oook
```

I am using boost xpressive regex_replace for this operation . This is my code

```
std::vector<QString>::iterator it = matchedText.begin();
wsregex regExp;
std::string strOut;
std::string::iterator itStr = strOut.begin(); ;
for( ; it != matchedText.end(); ++it )
 {
     regExp = wsregex::compile( (*it).toStdWString() );
     boost::xpressive::regex_replace( itStr, sObjectName.begin(), sObjectName.end(), regExp, qReplaceBy.toStdString(), regex_constants::format_perl );
 }
```

However the strOut contains ooook.
What am I missing ?

Comment: `"?o"` seems invalid, did you mean `".?o"` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes we are treating it internally that way

Comment: There are four matches; there are two occurrences of "oo" that match.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I used https://regex101.com/ using php regular expression